# Z3 Python API seems to be slow on linear formulae

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to use Z3 through its Python interface to infer the satisfiability of simple linear formulae. It seems to be quite slow even on simple formulae such as the following (composed of 10 clauses with 10 terms each) which I write down in the smt2 format:

```
(declare-fun x0 () Int)
(declare-fun x1 () Int)
(declare-fun x2 () Int)
(declare-fun x3 () Int)
(declare-fun x4 () Int)
(declare-fun x5 () Int)
(declare-fun x6 () Int)
(declare-fun x7 () Int)
(declare-fun x8 () Int)
(declare-fun x9 () Int)
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 84 x0)) (* 48 x1)) (* 55 x2)) (* -46 x3)) (* -8 x4)) (* -12 x5)) (* 34 x6)) (* 35 x7)) (* -36 x8)) (* 99 x9)) 77))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -66 x0)) (* -13 x1)) (* -81 x2)) (* -88 x3)) (* -42 x4)) (* 57 x5)) (* 46 x6)) (* -9 x7)) (* -39 x8)) (* 18 x9)) 4))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -18 x0)) (* 93 x1)) (* 23 x2)) (* 25 x3)) (* 63 x4)) (* 47 x5)) (* -68 x6)) (* -25 x7)) (* 49 x8)) (* 14 x9)) 78))
(assert (<= (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -44 x0)) (* -89 x1)) (* -48 x2)) (* -25 x3)) (* 40 x4)) (* 84 x5)) (* 40 x6)) (* 52 x7)) (* -8 x8)) (* 66 x9)) 5))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 30 x0)) (* 29 x1)) (* 64 x2)) (* 18 x3)) (* 63 x4)) (* -94 x5)) (* 20 x6)) (* -30 x7)) (* 60 x8)) (* -35 x9)) 72))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 97 x0)) (* -90 x1)) (* 74 x2)) (* -51 x3)) (* 70 x4)) (* 41 x5)) (* 31 x6)) (* 99 x7)) (* -34 x8)) (* 36 x9)) 60))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 38 x0)) (* -11 x1)) (* -82 x2)) (* -59 x3)) (* 93 x4)) (* 2 x5)) (* 69 x6)) (* 86 x7)) (* -83 x8)) (* 49 x9)) 14))
(assert (<= (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -55 x0)) (* 50 x1)) (* -48 x2)) (* -27 x3)) (* -7 x4)) (* 86 x5)) (* -15 x6)) (* 96 x7)) (* -46 x8)) (* 11 x9)) 56))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 50 x0)) (* -51 x1)) (* -32 x2)) (* -23 x3)) (* -75 x4)) (* 24 x5)) (* 39 x6)) (* -89 x7)) (* 8 x8)) (* 23 x9)) 36))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -50 x0)) (* 98 x1)) (* 62 x2)) (* -39 x3)) (* -90 x4)) (* 19 x5)) (* -10 x6)) (* 32 x7)) (* -51 x8)) (* 52 x9)) 24))
(check-sat)
```

I am generating these formulae dynamically using the following block of code:
(Notice: a formula is a list of clauses; a clause is a list of terms, a comparison sign and a free coefficient; a term is a pair variable-identifier (integer), coefficient of the variable (integer)).

```
import z3
from pyCloSE.formula import LE, SAT, UNSAT, UNKNOWN

context = z3.Context()
solver = z3.SolverFor("QF_LIA", context)

# Define all variables as integers.
definitions = dict()
for variable in formula.getVariables():
    definitions[variable] = z3.Int("x{}".format(variable), context) 

# Create assertions.
constraints = []
for clause in formula.getClauses(): 
    terms = [term.getCoefficient() * definitions[term.getIndex()] for term in clause.getTerms()]
    sumOfTerms = reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, terms)

    if clause.getComparison() == LE:
        constraints.append(sumOfTerms <= clause.getFreeCoefficient())
    else:
        constraints.append(sumOfTerms != clause.getFreeCoefficient())

solver.add(*constraints)
result = solver.check()
return result
```

The problem I am having is that Z3 is stuck on such a formula. It seems to be stuck too when I save it to a file named formula.smt2 and try to solve it through the bash Z3 command.

The version of the solver I am using is: Z3 version 4.3.2

Is the format I am using inconvenient or is it due to Z3? Is there any trick I could use to speed up the solving process?

As Juan Ospina suggested I tried to figure out which part of the formula was the difficult one for the solver. It seems it is the following:

```
(declare-fun x0 () Int)
(declare-fun x1 () Int)
(declare-fun x2 () Int)
(declare-fun x3 () Int)
(declare-fun x4 () Int)
(declare-fun x5 () Int)
(declare-fun x6 () Int)
(declare-fun x7 () Int)
(declare-fun x8 () Int)
(declare-fun x9 () Int)
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -18 x0)) (* 93 x1)) (* 23 x2)) (* 25 x3)) (* 63 x4)) (* 47 x5)) (* -68 x6)) (* -25 x7)) (* 49 x8)) (* 14 x9)) 78)) 
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 30 x0)) (* 29 x1)) (* 64 x2)) (* 18 x3)) (* 63 x4)) (* -94 x5)) (* 20 x6)) (* -30 x7)) (* 60 x8)) (* -35 x9)) 72)) 
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 97 x0)) (* -90 x1)) (* 74 x2)) (* -51 x3)) (* 70 x4)) (* 41 x5)) (* 31 x6)) (* 99 x7)) (* -34 x8)) (* 36 x9)) 60)) 
(assert (<= (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -55 x0)) (* 50 x1)) (* -48 x2)) (* -27 x3)) (* -7 x4)) (* 86 x5)) (* -15 x6)) (* 96 x7)) (* -46 x8)) (* 11 x9)) 56)) 
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* 50 x0)) (* -51 x1)) (* -32 x2)) (* -23 x3)) (* -75 x4)) (* 24 x5)) (* 39 x6)) (* -89 x7)) (* 8 x8)) (* 23 x9)) 36))
(assert (distinct (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 0 (* -50 x0)) (* 98 x1)) (* 62 x2)) (* -39 x3)) (* -90 x4)) (* 19 x5)) (* -10 x6)) (* 32 x7)) (* -51 x8)) (* 52 x9)) 24))
```

In fact if you remove any clause from this formula the solver is able to answer in less than a second while if you feed it with the entire formula it runs out of time.

Why does this happen? Is it normal that Z3 finds this formula so difficult to solve?

Best,
Andrea